# Can not use navigator.push in main Route Component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm new to react native and the title may be unclear.

Problem : can not use  `this.props.navigator.push` in `checkLoggedInToken()` function below. It says `this.props.navigator is undefined` But I can use same function in `Login` and `Signup` component.

Question : May be I can't access navigator like that in this main route class. What is the correct way to do that?

Below is my simplified codes

```
class AwesomeProject extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loaded: false
    };
    this.checkLoggedInToken();
  }

  renderScene(route, navigator) {
    if(route.id === "Signup"){
      return <Signup navigator={navigator} />
    }

    if(route.id === "Login"){
      return <Login navigator={navigator} />
    }
  }

  render() {
      return (
        <Navigator
          style={ styles.container }
          renderScene={ this.renderScene }
          initialRoute={{ id : 'Signup' , name : 'SIGNUP' }} />
      );
  }

  checkLoggedInToken(){ //Check token online with the stored one that is it legal , not expired
    this.props.navigator.push({
      id: 'Home',
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you should include your Home in renderScene and the function checkLoggedInToken should be called in the componentDidMount function.

```
class AwesomeProject extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loaded: false
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.checkLoggedInToken();
  }

  renderScene(route, navigator) {
    if(route.id === "Signup"){
      return <Signup navigator={navigator} />
    }

    if(route.id === "Login"){
      return <Login navigator={navigator} />
    }

    if (route.id === "Home") {
      return <Home navigator={navigator} />
    }
  }

  render() {
      return (
        <Navigator
          ref={(navigator) => this.navigator = navigator}
          style={ styles.container }
          renderScene={ this.renderScene }
          initialRoute={{ id : 'Signup' , name : 'SIGNUP' }} />
      );
  }

  checkLoggedInToken(){ //Check token online with the stored one that is it legal , not expired
    this.navigator.push({
      id: 'Home',
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: doesn't work  this.navigator and this.props.navigator is undefined :S

Comment: Where are you putting the console.log? Try inside componentDidMount

Comment: was logging in checkLoggedInToken but then i tried in componentDidMount as well  .. same thing undefined

Comment: Oh man, that actually work. It should have worked from the starting. At first I didn't notice you added `ref={(navigator) => this.navigator = navigator}` in Navigator as well untill I saw the example app and start comparing line by line. :S   All i read/understand from above was to componentDidMount . Thanks for your patient and actually make an example . Sorry too :)

Answer (score 0):

I think...in order to access navigator in your function checkLoggedInToken(). U have to reference navigator using refs.

ur render() should be like this...

```
render(){
  return (
    <Navigator
      ref={(ref) => this.navigator = ref}
      style={ styles.container }
      renderScene={ this.renderScene }
      initialRoute={{ id : 'Signup' , name : 'SIGNUP' }} />
  );
}
```

now u can access navigator in checkLoggedInToken() function..

```
checkLoggedInToken(){
  this.navigator.push({
    id: 'Home',
  });
}
```